# How to add folder to classpath?

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, pom.xml

I am adding new integration-test for a project. However, I am using vscode, and each time I open Java files under integration-test folder, I got a warning "*.java isn't on the classpath. Only syntax errors will be reported".

I had tried [Add A Class-Path Entry To The Manifest](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html#Add), [Additional Classpath Elements](https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-surefire-plugin-2.12.4/examples/configuring-classpath.html)
, etc. However, they couldn't help me to solve it.

How do I add folder `integration-test` into classpath? (.classpath is auto-genrated, I tried to modify it directly, but each time vscode re-open current project will rewrite the content). I hope any java files inside `integration-test` folder will just behave like the ones inside `main` or `test` folder. Especially I hope those test files could work with Java Test Runner extension.

Note: I didn't mean to load any resources from `integration-test` folder. I am hoping I could create, edit any Java files inside `integration-test` folder like all the Java files in `main` or `test` folder. Inside `integration-test`, it is just like a `test` folder, had a `java` folder etc. Right now, vscode will not auto-complete the package path for me when I used intellisense to autocomplete `class` snippet, and vscode can't recognize any public class that's already in `src/main/java/com...`.

Current folder structure inside `src`:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Mark the directory as a resources directory [using maven-resources-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html):

```xml
<project>
    ...
    <name>My Resources Plugin Practice Project</name>
    ...
    <build>
        ...
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/integration-test/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        ...
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also add new test resource folders.

```
<build>
  <testResources>
    <testResource>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
    </testResource>
    <testResource>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/integration-test/resources</directory>
    </testResource>
  </testResources>
</build>
```